# Do UAE residents {visa engineer} require a visa to visit Saudi Arabia?

Tags: visas, uae, saudi-arabia, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani National. I am working in UAE as a survey engineer. I want to visit some family friends in Saudi Arabia. I want to travel by bus. Do I need any type of visa to go directly to the Saudi border from Abu Dhabi to the Sila border? Will being stamped [In and Out] be enough there?

Comment: Except for citizens of the GCC, all nationals require visas to visit Saudi Arabia.

Answer (score 3):

Pakistani citizens [require visas for Saudi Arabia](http://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PK&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=SA&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), full stop.  There are no exceptions for UAE residents, although being resident and employed in the UAE may well increase your odds of getting the visa, since the Saudis are generally pretty picky about who they give visas to.